# messages={silent} not working with acro v2.4 package

Tags: acro

In `acro` package, version `v2.4` the option `messages={silent}` is not working as expected.

In the MWE below, the acronym is not defined. But with the option `messages={silent}` it should be ignored, issuing an error, but keep on with the compilation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{messages={silent}}

\begin{document}

\ac{AAA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error comes from deeper than `acro`, because it is `Missing number, treated as zero`, so a TeX error. It seems a bug in `acro`.

Comment: Bug messages are best made here https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro (and if something's not working as advertised I consider it a bug)

Comment: It is easier to put them here :). I may write in the bitbucket, but I do not know exactly where.

Comment: @cacamailg no, it's not easier – on bitbucket you can be sure that I'll see the issue and will try to find a fix. Here it is just luck that I saw your question so fast (and also that I remembered it today)… It's quite easy to find on bitbucket: click on *issues* and *create new*: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/new

Comment: @cacamailg actually the `silent` option *is* working: using an undefined acronym issues an acro warning, not an acro error. I fixed it anyway. The new version is available on https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro and will be uploaded to CTAN in the next days…

Comment: Ok. Thanks! In fact during compilation I see the warning, not an error, but the compilation stops. That is why I raised it as an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With v2.4a (2016/04/14) or newer there is no error any more.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}[2016/04/14]
\acsetup{messages={silent}}

\begin{document}

\ac{AAA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will need to wait for TeXLive 2016. However, I will accept your answer. Thanks for taking care of this "bug".